# Need some help combining 2 on clicks into one

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, onclick

I have a on click that closes a expanded div, I have a on click inside that console logs the array object.

How can I alter my function to get the array object on the first on click whilst still keeping the same functionality the first on click is set to do ?

```
_bindShowLess = function () {
        var _showLess = _sectorPageStrengths.find('.view-all-sectors-btn.less');

        _showLess.on('click', function () {

            var sliders = [].slice.call(document.getElementsByClassName("sectorpage-strengths"));

            sliders.forEach(function (element, index){
                element.addEventListener("click", function(){
                    console.log("array" +index + "!");
                });
            });

            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: _sectorPageStrengths.offset().top
            }, 700);
        });
    };
```

I have tried the following code however it now dose not console log the div array object I am on, but all objects.

```
_bindShowLess = function () {
        var _showLess = _sectorPageStrengths.find('.view-all-sectors-btn.less');

        _showLess.on('click', function () {

            var sliders = [].slice.call(document.getElementsByClassName("sectorpage-strengths"));

            sliders.forEach(function (element, index){
                // element.addEventListener("click", function(){
                    console.log("array" +index + "!");
                // });
            });

            // $('html, body').stop().animate({
            //     scrollTop: $(index).offset().top - 50
            // }, 700);

            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: _sectorPageStrengths.offset().top
            }, 700);
        });
    };
    init = function () {
        var EachView = jQuery('.sectorpage-strengths');
        EachView.each(function (index, element) {
            _checkElemnt($(element));
            _bindShowMore(element); // Individual container Fix Ben(2018)
            _bindShowLess();
            $(window).on('load', function () {
                equalHeight();
            });
        });

        $("#loadPDFComponentModal").on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
            $("#hiddenIframe").html("");
        });
    };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand your question fully... Is this what you're looking for?

```
_bindShowLess = function () {
    var _showLess = _sectorPageStrengths.find('.view-all-sectors-btn.less');

    _showLess.on('click', function () {

        var sliders = [].slice.call(document.getElementsByClassName("sectorpage-strengths"));

        var indices = [];

        sliders.forEach(function (element, index){
                indices.push("array" +index + "!");
        });
        console.table('Array indices!', indices);

        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: _sectorPageStrengths.offset().top
        }, 700);
    });
};
```

Comment: I get Uncaught TypeError: indices.append is not a function error with this

Comment: @Beep Updated the code. Should've been `indices.push`. When stuff like that comes up, it can help to search for the error on Google as well. Array.append isn't a function but Array.push is. :)

Comment: Hmm still print out all the arrays not the individual array im clicking on